# selectAnnotation does not show callout

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, mkmapview

I want to change the callout shown on the MKMapView.  When I call

```
[self.mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
```

it pans the map to the annotation, but does not show its callout.  How do I get it to show the callout?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `title`, and optionally the `subtitle` property on the annotation object. MapKit will automatically show a callout.

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;

@end
```

And the implementation,

```
#import "MyAnnotation.h"

@implementation MyAnnotation

@synthesize title, subtitle;

@end
```

Usage,

```
MyAnnotation *foo = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
foo.title = @"I am Foo";
foo.subtitle = "I am jus' a subtitle";
```

Comment: That did not work (note that my annotation is my own class which subclasses MKAnnotation.  So I have my own getter for title.  How did you propose I set the title?

Comment: Your custom class should implement the protocol `MKAnnotation`. Add a property for `title` and `subtitle` in your class. Will add a full example.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the MKAnnotation Delegate method

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewIdentifier = @"AnnotationViewIdentifier";

    MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView  dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewIdentifier];
    if (annotationView == nil) 
    {
       annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewIdentifier]autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

    return annotationView;
}
```